# JW Player Social Lock

Tags: facebook-like, jwplayer, facebook-social-plugins

I am trying to find or create a function in JW Player that restricts users from viewing the video if they didn't liked a page.
There are many scripts like this for youtube and vimeo but not a single one for jw player.
Did someone had any success with this?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have an example of one such script for a different player?

Comment: This is a example of a wordpress plugin for youtube and vimeo only. http://codecanyon.net/item/social-video-locker-for-wordpress/full_screen_preview/2861710

Comment: We don't have anything out of the box for the JW Player that does this. You could build your own plugin though, we have a plugin sdk available here - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/